# Memory leak in python for loop even if I delete all variables at the end of each iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, memory-leaks, cupy

The following two loops will use memory until I run out, but I can't figure out why. I am deleting all of the created variables at the end of each iteration and it still leaks.

```
!pip3 install cupy-cuda101
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

xtrain = cp.asnumpy(cp.random.uniform(-1,1,size = (150000,50)))

for i in range(0,1000):
   weights = cp.random.uniform(-1,1,size = (1275,1000))
   
   for chunk in range(0,xtrain.shape[0],5000):
      xchunk = xtrain[chunk:chunk+5000,:]
      poly=PolynomialFeatures(interaction_only = True, include_bias = False)
      xchunk = cp.array(poly.fit_transform(xchunk))
      ranks = cp.matmul(xchunk,weights)
      del ranks, xchunk, poly
   del weights
```

xtrain is just float data as well, between -1 and 1.

Comment: All your `del` statements are pointless, since those variables are re-assigned on each iteration anyway.

Comment: exactly, so how can it use more and more memory after each iteration?

Comment: No idea. You have to provide a [mcve] to really expect anyone to be able to diagnose something like taht

Comment: ok there its reproducible now

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why you think there is a "leak"? Also note that CuPy uses the memory pool by default: https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/reference/memory.html

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Do you run out of memory as in "an error is thrown"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these lines insert at the end of each iteration fixed it:

```
    cp.get_default_memory_pool().free_all_blocks()
    cp.get_default_pinned_memory_pool().free_all_blocks()
```